# Creating a "mapping" in Excel and using it to fill a column based on existing data in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

The problem to solve is:
There are many "document numbers" that need to be mapped between project A and project B. Let's say the mapping rules are the following, stored in the spreadsheet somewhere:

[image: mapping rules]

Elsewhere in the spreadsheet, there is a column of "A" documents. This will contain both the document number as in the above screenshot, as well as a description. The next column is to be filled with the corresponding "B" document numbers only, as per the above mapping rules. So, in the following example, cell AD4 should contain "85_12", and cell AD7 should contain "85_56". In other words, all cells in that column should be checked if they contain "A" document numbers, and the the adjacent cells in the next column should be filled with the corresponding "B" document numbers.

[image]

The following formula looks like a good starting point: 
`IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AA12", AC4)))`. In this case, it will check if cell AC4 contains "AA12", which it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following array formula:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH(1,--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:$A$5,E2)),0))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]